# Converting from working function in console to working script. (See Edit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to automate a clicking of a link within a class list. Currently I have a working script that will pick the first item in the container using the querySelector(), one line of code wrapped in a function.
To have more usability, I was wondering if I could modify the code so that the script searches within each item in the container trying to match a title of the listing or name with a defined variable, to the users desire, and once found, clicks the link for that particular item.

```
<div class="item-wall">
    <div class="grid-item" data-column-index="0" data-pdpurl="http://www.LINK1.com">
        <div class="grid-item"> … </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="grid-item-details-wrapper">
                <div class="grid-item-image"> … </div>
                <div class="grid-item-info-wrapper no-chipper">
                    <a href="http://www.LINK1.com">
                        <div class="product-name">
                             <p class="griditem-display-name nsg-font-size--regular nsg-text--dark-grey">
                                 PRODUCT1
                             </p>
                             <p class="griditem-subtitle nsg-font-size--regular nsg-text--medium-grey"> … </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-price-wrapper"> … </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item-extras"> … </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item" data-column-index="1" data-pdpurl="http://www.LINK2.com">
        <div class="grid-item"> … </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="grid-item-details-wrapper">
                <div class="grid-item-image"> … </div>
                <div class="grid-item-info-wrapper no-chipper">
                    <a href="http://www.LINK2.com">
                        <div class="product-name">
                             <p class="griditem-display-name nsg-font-size--regular nsg-text--dark-grey">
                                 PRODUCT2
                             </p>
                             <p class="griditem-subtitle nsg-font-size--regular nsg-text--medium-grey"> … </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-price-wrapper"> … </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item-extras"> … </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="paging-bar hidden"> … </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Sorry for being so verbose. The web page has an 'item-wall' with several items, 2 are only shown here. I wish to be able to set a variable as a string in the script and be able to use something along the lines of .contain() to find an instance of the matching product name in the wall and then have it open the link corresponding to the selection. 
Thanks for any input!

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EDIT: Thanks to @Barmar for the working console function:

```
function product_click(product) {
    $(".griditem-display-name:contains("+product+")").closest("a").click();
}
product_click("Desirable here")
```

Now I am at a loss as to how to make this function operational in an script. I've tried with scriptish in firefox and have tried writing this to a .js file and loading it as an unpacked extension in chrome to no avail. It seems as though the function/script won't load. If anyone has any thoughts, they'd be greatly appreciated.
Thanks again!

Comment: Trying to understand. You want a function that can be given the string `PRODUCT1`, and it will click on `www.LINK1.com`, or given `PRODUCT2` will click on `www.LINK2.com`, is that right?

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. Exactly @Barmar Something like: var want = "string of what to search for in here" would be defined at the top where the user could put like "black shirt". The item wall could have black, blue, red, and green shirts, but the script will use the declaration to search for the black shirt and match it with which 'PRODUCT'1-5 it is and open that link.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is it:

```
function product_click(product) {
    $(".griditem-display-name:contains("+product+")").closest("a").click();
}
```

Comment: Is the product parameter passed in the function definition a variable declared with the string of the desired product? Thanks again!

Comment: It can be anything, that's up to the function that calls `product_click`.

Comment: So when I make the function call, I pass the string parameter? Could I also have it take no parameters and in the .contains() pass the string there where "+product+" is? Thank you for the help. I'm rather rusty.

Comment: Yes, you pass the string parameter. You could hard-code the string in the function if you want. But then it would only work for a particular product -- don't you want to be able to click on different products based on conditions?

Comment: Very true, I was just seeing for test purposes. I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

Comment: Add what you're trying to your question, and make a fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Say, for instance, this is from what to choose from. [Click Here](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/n/d1u?cp=usns_twit_110213_nsw_monotones) I'm trying to test the function you used with this, changing class names of course. When I call product_click("Force"), nothing happens. Also, I'm testing with the scriptish extension in firefox as well as an unpacked extension in chrome.

Comment: I had a typo, `#.` should have been just `.`. `$(".griditem-display-name:contains(Force)")` finds the entry for Nike Air Force 1 Low SP now.

Comment: I just ran `product_click('Force')` from the Javascript console and it worked.

Comment: I figured to ignore the #. I'm still having no luck. =/ Also, when you ran the function with contains(Force), it had no parameters, right? I'm just doing this until I can find out how to insert a user defined variable.

Comment: I don't know anything about the extensions you're testing with. I just pasted my function into the Javascript console in Chrome and called it, and it worked.

Comment: For simplicity, I just have this script running on window load with only this function until I can troubleshoot it. I'm also testing in the javascript console in chrome and see that it is working there. Thank you for all of your help. I just need to figure out how to port this to a script for my friend. Thanks again @Barmar